# Cut video same lenght as another video same name

Tags: powershell

I have recorded some videos with the same length of 40 seconds.
I have old videos with the same name but the length varies between 28-38 seconds.
I want the new videos to be cut to the same length as the old ones. The new and old has the same names. Is it possible with a script using ffmpeg?

Get the length of the old video then cut the new video with same name to the same length as the old. Windows powershell or command bat file.

It's only the end of the video that has to be cut

Comment: Sounds as that this is a question for usage of `ffmpeg`. I think this question is off-topic here and should be asked at superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the path for `ffprobe.exe` and `ffmpeg.exe` in your PATH environment variable
(like `'C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\'`), then you can use this code below:

```
# the folders where the old and the new videos can be found
$oldVideoPath = 'X:\path\to\OLD\videos'
$newVideoPath = 'X:\path\to\NEW\videos'

# get a list of the old video files; filenames only
$oldVidNames = (Get-ChildItem -Path $oldVideoPath -File).Name
# get the new video files and loop over them
(Get-ChildItem -Path $newVideoPath -File) | 
    Where-Object { $oldVidNames -contains $_.Name } | ForEach-Object {
        # construct the full path to the old video from which we take the duration
        $oldVideo = Join-Path -Path $oldVideoPath -ChildPath $_.Name
        # construct the full path to the trimmed output file (append '_trimmed')
        $trimmedVideo = Join-Path -Path $newVideoPath -ChildPath ('{0}_trimmed{1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension)

        # get the duration of the old video in format HH:mm:ss.ffffff
        $oldDuration = ffprobe -i "$oldVideo" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal
        Write-Host "Trimming '$($_.FullName)' to duration $oldDuration"

        # now trim the new video to the same length, overwriting the original by using switch '-y'
        ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:00 -i "$($_.FullName)" -to $oldDuration -c:v copy -c:a copy "$trimmedVideo" -loglevel quiet
    }
```

If you do **not** have that PATH environment variable, you need to use variables containing the full path and filenames to both ffprobe and ffmpeg like this:

```
# the file paths to both ffprobe and ffmpeg if you do not have the path to the bin folder in your PATH environment variable
$ffprobe = 'C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe'
$ffmpeg  = 'C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe'

# the folders where the old and the new videos can be found
$oldVideoPath = 'X:\path\to\OLD\videos'
$newVideoPath = 'X:\path\to\NEW\videos'

# get a list of the old video files; filenames only
$oldVidNames = (Get-ChildItem -Path $oldVideoPath -File).Name
# get the new video files and loop over them
(Get-ChildItem -Path $newVideoPath -File) | 
    Where-Object { $oldVidNames -contains $_.Name } | ForEach-Object {
        # construct the full path to the old video from which we take the duration
        $oldVideo = Join-Path -Path $oldVideoPath -ChildPath $_.Name
        # construct the full path to the trimmed output file (append '_trimmed')
        $trimmedVideo = Join-Path -Path $newVideoPath -ChildPath ('{0}_trimmed{1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension)

        # get the duration of the old video in format HH:mm:ss.ffffff
        $oldDuration = & $ffprobe -i "$oldVideo" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal
        Write-Host "Trimming '$($_.FullName)' to duration $oldDuration"

        # now trim the new video to the same length, overwriting the original by using switch '-y'
        & $ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:00 -i "$($_.FullName)" -to $oldDuration -c:v copy -c:a copy "$trimmedVideo" -loglevel quiet
    }
```

ffmpeg switches:

```
-y               overwrite output file if exists
-i               specifies the input file
-ss              the startposition in the input file (here `00:00:00` to start from the very beginning)
-to              specifies duration from start to end (this value is taken from the old file with the same name)
-c:v copy        trim video via stream copy (fast)
-c:a copy        trim audio via stream copy (fast)
-loglevel quiet  do not send output via error stream to console
```

ffprobe switches:

```
-i                              specifies the input file
-show_entries format=duration   set list of entries to show, in this case we only want duration
-v quiet                        do not send output via error stream to console
-of csv="p=0"                   set output printing format to csv; do not print section name
-sexagesimal                    Use sexagesimal format HH:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS for time values.
```

Comment: @fomt Thanks. Being new to the platform you may not know this, but it is customary to mark the question 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left. This helps others with a similar question finding it more easily.